# how to use fetch in Hibernate Query Language

Tags: hibernate, hql

This is not a techincal problem, just a syntax correction that I am not getting.

I have hibernate 3.6 and I have mapped my model classes in the xml files. The default type mentioned in those xml files are that these classes are to be brought as lazily. Since its hardcoded, I cannot change that behaviour.

The model that I am trying to bring looks like this.

```
class A {
    private int id;
    private B b;
    private C c;
}
```

The classes B and C needs to be loaded eagerly in my case.

SO I wrote the query like this.

```
from A.class.getName() a where a.id = :id;
```

In this query, where do I put the fetch keyword.
Below one throws errors:

```
from A.class.getName a fetch where a.id = :id;
```

In examples on the internet, they are doing some joins on the query and then getting some values like this:

```
from Cat as cat inner join fetch cat.mate left join fetch cat.kittens
```

However, in my case, all the joins are done internally in the xml files. I don't have to do joins in the query. So where do I put the "fetch" keyword to state that initiate all the linked classes (B and C) also at the same time non-lazily.

Note:

1. I cannot use criteria api because I don't want to add additional jars in my project.

Comment: What do you mean by `all the joins are done internally in the xml files`? Why you can not use something like what you put as a sample from net? `from A a inner join fetch a.b as b where a.id=:id`

Comment: in my xml files, I already have one-to-many and many-to-many relationship defined. Then why do I need to explicitly join in the hql? I just want to use the hql query to tell it to fetch all the associated classes, not to join again. Am I correct?

Comment: `fetch` is used to override `lazy-eager` behavior of relationships. If you have `b` as a `lazy` loaded association, you can use fetch to force hibernate to load `b` eagerly. If `b` is `eager` loaded, you don't need `fetch`.

Comment: here is the doco to read: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: I read the article. But that is my question!! you said fetch is used to override the behavior. My behavior is defined to be lazy loaded, and I want it to override to do eager. But I do not want to join because its already done in the xml files. What would be the syntax for fetch without having to join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is

```
select a from A a
left join fetch a.b
left join fetch a.c
where a.id = :id
```

Relevant part of [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins):

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the mapping file for associations and collections. See [Section 20.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching), “Fetching strategies” for more information.
>
> ```
> from Cat as cat
> inner join fetch cat.mate
> left join fetch cat.kittens
> ```

Comment: okay..now I get it. So if I want to initialize just the B class, I would write query like: from A.class.getName() a left join fetch a.b where a.id=:id  and this way in the A class, only B will be eager, but C will still be lazy? Correct?

Comment: hi. just to contribute to your answer - I found one more solution and posted it here. Do you feel its correct?

Answer (score 2):

One more answer that I found, and which is very interesting.

If you are willing to write a native SQL query, you could use the addJoin() method in the hiberate. In the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e13732) , under section "16.1.3. Handling associations and collections",

The example is:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT c.ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE, DOG_ID, D_ID, D_NAME FROM CATS c, DOGS d WHERE c.DOG_ID = d.D_ID")
 .addEntity("cat", Cat.class)
 .addJoin("cat.dog");

It is possible to eagerly join in the Dog to avoid the possible extra roundtrip for initializing the proxy. This is done via the addJoin() method, which allows you to join in an association or collection.
```

So you can easily eagerly load all your associated classes like this.